# json file not arriving complete when using sockets

Tags: java, python, sockets

I have a stream of video. And every frame I need to send a small json file with data from that frame, speed it´s crucial. Whats the best way to do this?

My Server is something like this. Waits for a json file and then has to send that json file to a python application.

```
public class ServerClass  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Marcoserver mimarco=new Marcoserver();                  
    }   
}

class Marcoserver implements Runnable {

    public Marcoserver(){               
        Thread miHilo = new Thread(this);       
        miHilo.start();     
    }   

    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(7777);

            while (true) {
                Socket miSocket = server.accept(); 

                BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(miSocket.getInputStream(), "UTF8"));
                String mensaje = entrada.readLine();

                JSONObject obj;
                obj = new JSONObject(mensaje);
                System.out.println(obj);

                ConectorSocket cntor = new ConectorSocket("localhost", 6363);   
                cntor.Conectar();
                cntor.Send(mensaje);
                cntor.Close();

                miSocket.close();
            }   

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

}


public class ConectorSocket{

        private String host;
        private int port;
        Socket sockSend;

        public ConnectClass(String hst, int prt ) {
            this.host = hst;
            this.port = prt;
        }

        public void Conectar() {
            this.sockSend = new Socket(this.host, this.port);
        }
        public void Send(String mensaje) {
            DataOutputStream flujo_salida = new DataOutputStream(sockSend.getOutputStream());
            flujo_salida.writeBytes(mensaje);
            flujo_salida.close();
        }
        public boolean Close() {
            this.sockSend.close();
        }

}
```

This is the python app simplified:

```
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('localhost', 6666))
serversocket.listen()

while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(2048)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print(buf.decode())
```

My problem is that the python app prints incomplete information such as:

```
{"keyword"
{"keyword": [[14, 1, -1]]}
{"keyword": [[14,
```

instead of:

```
{"keyword":[]}
{"keyword":[[14,1,-1]]}
{"keyword":[[14,2,-1]]}
```

Comment: This is my complete code

Comment: ConectorSocket == ConectorClass ?

Comment: yes! sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with your Java code, but your Python code is not good:

```
while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    buf = connection.recv(2048)
    if len(buf) > 0:
        print(buf.decode())
```

That will print just the first received TCP packet for each connection.

You need to continue calling `recv` until it returns `0`:

```
while True:
    connection, address = serversocket.accept()
    msg = []
    while True:
        buf = connection.recv(65536)
        if (len(buf) == 0):
            break
        msg.append(buf)
    print(''.join(msg))
    connection.close()
```

You also need to close each connection.

Comment: If the connection is local and the amount of data is significant, it's faster to collect chunks in a list, and then `''.join(...)` it. In that case, 2048 is overly conservative, too.

Comment: @9000 I'm sure performance isn't an issue for the OP at this stage. But ok, updated.